# Timeout error in SELECT request with timestamp range

Tags: cassandra, cql, cqlsh

#### Here's my situation :

- VPS Server :

  - 1 Cassandra Database :

    - Keyspace : "atim_cloud"

      - Table : "messages"

```html
CREATE TABLE atim_cloud.messages (
    deviceid text,
    channelname text,
    time timestamp,
    avgsignal float,
    latitude float,
    longitude float,
    rssi float,
    snr float,
    stationid text,
    value blob,
    valuetype text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((deviceid, channelname), time)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (time DESC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = '{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"NONE"}'
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'min_threshold': '4', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32'}
    AND compression = {'sstable_compression': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE';
CREATE INDEX messages_deviceid_idx ON atim_cloud.messages (deviceid);
CREATE INDEX messages_channelname_idx ON atim_cloud.messages (channelname);
CREATE INDEX messages_time_idx ON atim_cloud.messages (time);
```

### My problem :

This table was made for big quantity of data (millions of rows). 
Simple request works fine like :

```html
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE deviceid ='1DB8D';
```

And I get :

```html
 deviceid | channelname | time                     | avgsignal | latitude | longitude | rssi   | snr   | stationid | value      | valuetype
----------+-------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+-----------+--------+-------+-----------+------------+-----------
    1DB8D |      INDEX1 | 2015-07-26 22:21:59+0200 |       9.9 |       45 |         6 | -125.5 |  9.66 |      0E00 | 0x00000000 |       int
    1DB8D |      INDEX1 | 2015-07-26 22:11:58+0200 |      9.89 |       45 |         6 | -125.5 |  9.85 |      0E00 | 0x00000000 |       int
    1DB8D |      INDEX1 | 2015-07-26 22:01:59+0200 |      9.87 |       45 |         6 | -123.5 | 10.08 |      0E00 | 0x00000000 |       int
    1DB8D |      INDEX1 | 2015-07-26 21:51:59+0200 |      9.83 |       45 |         6 | -125.5 |   9.8 |      0E00 | 0x00000000 |       int
    1DB8D |      INDEX1 | 2015-07-26 21:41:59+0200 |      9.83 |       45 |         6 | -124.5 | 10.02 |      0E00 | 0x00000000 |       int
    1DB8D |      INDEX1 | 2015-07-26 21:31:58+0200 |       9.8 |       45 |         6 | -126.5 | 10.35 |      0E00 | 0x00000000 |       int
    1DB8D |      INDEX1 | 2015-07-26 21:21:59+0200 |      9.78 |       45 |         6 | -122.5 |  9.91 |      0E00 | 0x00000000 |       int
    1DB8D |      INDEX1 | 2015-07-26 21:11:59+0200 |      9.82 |       45 |         6 | -130.5 |  8.85 |      0E00 | 0x00000000 |       int
    1DB8D |      INDEX1 | 2015-07-26 21:01:59+0200 |      9.79 |       45 |         6 | -129.5 | 10.11 |      0E00 | 0x00000000 |       int
    1DB8D |      INDEX1 | 2015-07-26 20:51:58+0200 |      9.77 |       45 |         6 | -124.5 | 10.06 |      0E00 | 0x00000000 |       int
    1DB8D |      INDEX1 | 2015-07-26 20:41:59+0200 |      9.78 |       45 |         6 | -123.5 |  9.52 |      0E00 | 0x00000000 |       int
```

But when i do some more complexe request with timestamp's compute like :
(It happens a few times but not all the time)

```html
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE deviceid = '1DB8D' AND time >= 1437981692831 LIMIT 500 ALLOW FILTERING ;
```

or simply :

```html
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM messages ;
```

I get (after some second. Timeout i guess):

```html
errors={}, last_host=127.0.0.1
```

Do you have any suggestion to solve my problem ? 
I'm looking for some advice about Index, or Primary Key but I haven't found any thing.

If you have some tips to perform this datatable, i'm glad to hear it. What about multi-cluster ? I don't understand everything about it.

Thank you ;)

Answer (score 3):

Secondary indexes are only recommended for fields with low cardinality.  They are very inefficient for fields with high cardinality such as your time field.  That is why you will get timeout errors when you use your time field in a query.

In Cassandra you should concentrate on using good primary keys rather than fixing schema problems by creating secondary keys.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,

I read something like that (high-cardinality and index are not friend) in Documenation about INDEX in Datastax so I remove my index on time with 'DROP INDEX' command but nothing happened.

What do you mean by secondary index ? Do I have to rebuild my Table with new primaries keys like that ? Should I keep my INDEX on 'time' column ?:

PRIMARY KEY (deviceid, channelname)

Thank you again for your quick answer.

Comment: It sounds like you are coming from a relational database background, but Cassandra is very different from an RDBMS due to its distributed nature.  A good place to start might be this article http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/a-deep-look-to-the-cql-where-clause

Comment: Thank for the url. But I'm still lost. Can you tell me directly what I have to do in my situation ?

Comment: Your question is very broad.  In general you need to structure your schema so that your queries use only the partition keys and clustering columns.  Do not create indexes.  If necessary you may need to create multiple tables with different keys (i.e. use denormalization techniques) to support the queries you want to do.

Comment: As I understand : I don't have to use Indexes just Primary keys ... hmmm OK. But as we can see : deviceid and channelname are my partition key and timestamp is clustering key. What is wrong with this structure ?
Sorry if i don't understand ... I just need a table where I can request my table with command like :
 - SELECT * FROM messages WHERE deviceid = XXX AND channelname = XXX AND (timestamp >= XXXX AND timestamp <= XXXX);

Comment: That query should work with your current schema without indexes.  If you specify all parts of the partition key, then you can do a range query on your clustering column.  In your original question you were not specifying the channelname and were relying on inefficient secondary indexes.

Comment: And if i don't want to add "Channelname" in my query ? because some times I need it but other times, i don't. Does it change lot of things in my structure ?

Comment: It might mean you'll want a second table that does not have channelname as part of the key.  When you add data, you'd insert it into both tables.

Comment: It's a little bit messy ! You don't think ? I believed than Cassandra was able to do more complex operations.

Comment: In Cassandra 3.0 they are introducing materialized views, which would maintain the two tables for you.  But for now if you want two views like this you will have to maintain the two tables in your application.

Answer (score 1):

Just to echo what Jim said, but secondary indexes were not really intended to be a "magic bullet," used to fix the shortcomings of your data model.  What you will want to do is build your data model around your queries.

Just curious, but what is `channelname` used for?  You have it as a partition key, but it looks like you really don't want to query by it.  Are you using it as a "bucket" to help keep your columns-per-partition under 2 billion?  Or is it just for extra uniqueness?

Assuming you don't need it as a "bucket," if I restructure your PRIMARY KEY like this:

```
PRIMARY KEY (deviceid, time, channelname)
```

Then, this query works:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow2> SELECT * FROM messages WHERE deviceid ='1DB8D';

 deviceid | time                     | channelname | avgsignal | latitude | longitude | rssi   | snr   | stationid | value      | valuetype
----------+--------------------------+-------------+-----------+----------+-----------+--------+-------+-----------+------------+-----------
    1DB8D | 2015-07-26 15:21:59-0500 |      INDEX1 |       9.9 |       45 |         6 | -125.5 |  9.66 |      0E00 | 0x00000000 |       int
    1DB8D | 2015-07-26 15:11:58-0500 |      INDEX1 |      9.89 |       45 |         5 | -125.5 |  9.85 |      0E00 | 0x00000000 |       int
    1DB8D | 2015-07-26 15:01:59-0500 |      INDEX1 |      9.87 |       45 |         5 | -123.5 | 10.08 |      0E00 | 0x00000000 |       int
    1DB8D | 2015-07-26 14:51:59-0500 |      INDEX1 |      9.83 |       45 |         5 | -125.5 |   9.8 |      0E00 | 0x00000000 |       int
    1DB8D | 2015-07-26 14:41:59-0500 |      INDEX1 |      9.83 |       45 |         5 | -124.5 | 10.02 |      0E00 | 0x00000000 |       int
    1DB8D | 2015-07-26 14:31:58-0500 |      INDEX1 |       9.8 |       45 |         5 | -126.5 | 10.35 |      0E00 | 0x00000000 |       int
    1DB8D | 2015-07-26 14:21:59-0500 |      INDEX1 |      9.78 |       45 |         5 | -122.5 |  9.91 |      0E00 | 0x00000000 |       int
    1DB8D | 2015-07-26 14:11:59-0500 |      INDEX1 |      9.82 |       45 |         5 | -130.5 |  8.85 |      0E00 | 0x00000000 |       int
    1DB8D | 2015-07-26 14:01:59-0500 |      INDEX1 |      9.79 |       45 |         5 | -129.5 | 10.11 |      0E00 | 0x00000000 |       int
    1DB8D | 2015-07-26 13:51:58-0500 |      INDEX1 |      9.77 |       45 |         5 | -124.5 | 10.06 |      0E00 | 0x00000000 |       int
    1DB8D | 2015-07-26 13:41:59-0500 |      INDEX1 |      9.78 |       45 |         5 | -123.5 |  9.52 |      0E00 | 0x00000000 |       int

(11 rows)
```

As does this one:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow2> SELECT * FROM messages WHERE deviceid ='1DB8D' AND time >='2015-07-26 14:00:00-0500';

 deviceid | time                     | channelname | avgsignal | latitude | longitude | rssi   | snr   | stationid | value      | valuetype
----------+--------------------------+-------------+-----------+----------+-----------+--------+-------+-----------+------------+-----------
    1DB8D | 2015-07-26 15:21:59-0500 |      INDEX1 |       9.9 |       45 |         6 | -125.5 |  9.66 |      0E00 | 0x00000000 |       int
    1DB8D | 2015-07-26 15:11:58-0500 |      INDEX1 |      9.89 |       45 |         5 | -125.5 |  9.85 |      0E00 | 0x00000000 |       int
    1DB8D | 2015-07-26 15:01:59-0500 |      INDEX1 |      9.87 |       45 |         5 | -123.5 | 10.08 |      0E00 | 0x00000000 |       int
    1DB8D | 2015-07-26 14:51:59-0500 |      INDEX1 |      9.83 |       45 |         5 | -125.5 |   9.8 |      0E00 | 0x00000000 |       int
    1DB8D | 2015-07-26 14:41:59-0500 |      INDEX1 |      9.83 |       45 |         5 | -124.5 | 10.02 |      0E00 | 0x00000000 |       int
    1DB8D | 2015-07-26 14:31:58-0500 |      INDEX1 |       9.8 |       45 |         5 | -126.5 | 10.35 |      0E00 | 0x00000000 |       int
    1DB8D | 2015-07-26 14:21:59-0500 |      INDEX1 |      9.78 |       45 |         5 | -122.5 |  9.91 |      0E00 | 0x00000000 |       int
    1DB8D | 2015-07-26 14:11:59-0500 |      INDEX1 |      9.82 |       45 |         5 | -130.5 |  8.85 |      0E00 | 0x00000000 |       int
    1DB8D | 2015-07-26 14:01:59-0500 |      INDEX1 |      9.79 |       45 |         5 | -129.5 | 10.11 |      0E00 | 0x00000000 |       int

(9 rows)
```

What is more important, is that they work without secondary indexes or the `ALLOW FILTERING` directive.  This PRIMARY KEY also supports complete partition key (`deviceid`) queries, so these queries should perform well.

> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM messages ;

Yeah, the Cassandra/CQL implementation of `COUNT` doesn't perform nearly as well as it's RDBMS/SQL cousin.  Apple's Richard Low (and DataStax MVP) wrote an article ("[Counting Keys In Cassandra](http://www.planetcassandra.org/blog/counting-key-in-cassandra/)") about how `COUNT` works "under the hood," and it's definitely worth a read.  Essentially, `COUNT` has to iterate through EVERY ROW to give you that number.  So if you are running that against a large column family (table), that *will* time-out.

Note: If you find that you *do* need a bucket (to keep your columns-per-partition below 2 billion) you could pick a time/date increment that makes sense for your data, and query within that window.  For instance, above you could make the date your bucket (as a `text` field) build your partition key as `PRIMARY KEY ((deviceid, datebucket), time, channelname)` and then query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE deviceid ='1DB8D' AND datebucket='20150726';
```

Maybe see if something like that makes sense for you.

**EDIT:** Patrick McFadin of DataStax wrote a great article on [Getting Started With Time Series Data Modeling](http://academy.datastax.com/demos/getting-started-time-series-data-modeling).  In this article he describes using a "time bucket" to further partition a table in a time series application.  This saves you from hitting the 2 billion column-per-partition limit, and also helps Cassandra avoid (older) data that you don't really care about at that moment.

Comment: Thank you Bryce for your answer. For more details : a device (deviceid) own several channel (channelname) with different kind of data.

Most of the time, i need to get my data in function of deviceid and channelname : SELECT * FROM messages WHERE deviceid=X AND channelname=X LIMIT 500; 

And other time, I need to request my table for an import function or dynamic refresh in my website, so i need time column like :
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE deviceid=X AND time<=X

Comment: I don't really understand the 'bucket' system you describe ... 
Concerning request, i didn't say it never work but it doesn't work for device with lot of message already saved in this database (about 10 000).
For more precision, this table should be able to compute millions of rows. This table may have to treat 1 new message/ second approximately, so about 30 millions messages after one year.

Comment: Thank your for URL article, i'm gonna read it. But I don't think it necesarry because i don't think the table will be bigger than 2 billion points (or not before 10 years). So do you believe i set 3 partitions keys (deviceid, channelname, time) and it will works ?
Do you have any method to transfer data from old table to the new one ?

Answer (score 0):

I get time to try solution you gave me :
So I created 2 others tables to try different request (I need at less, this 3 requests as following) :

```sql
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE deviceid = '1DB8D' AND time >= 1438853606718 ALLOW FILTERING ; 
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE deviceid = '1DB8D' AND channelname = 'brutMessage'; 
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE deviceid = '1DB8D' AND channelname = 'brutMessage' AND time >= 1438853606718;
```

So here's my results :

#### First table (messages): the old one

```sql
PRIMARY KEY ((deviceid, channelname), time) ) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (time DESC)
```

```sql
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE deviceid = '1DB8D' AND time >= 1438853606718 ALLOW FILTERING ;  <==== errors={}, last_host=127.0.0.1
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE deviceid = '1DB8D' AND channelname = 'brutMessage'; <=== OK
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE deviceid = '1DB8D' AND channelname = 'brutMessage' AND time >= 1438853606718; <=== OK
```

---

#### Second table (messages_test):

```sql
PRIMARY KEY (deviceid, time, channelname)) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (time DESC, channelname ASC)
```

```sql
SELECT * FROM messages_test WHERE deviceid = '1DB8D' AND time >= 1438853606718 ; <==== OK
SELECT * FROM messages_test WHERE deviceid = '1DB8D' AND channelname='brutMessage' AND time >= 1438853606718 ; <==== code=2200 [Invalid query] message="PRIMARY KEY column "channelname" cannot be restricted 
                                                                                                                    (preceding column "ColumnDefinition{name=time, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.ReversedType
                                                                                                                    (org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.TimestampType), kind=CLUSTERING_COLUMN, componentIndex=0, 
                                                                                                                    indexName=null, indexType=null}" is either not restricted or by a non-EQ relation)"
                                                                                                                    
SELECT * FROM messages_test WHERE deviceid = '1DB8D' AND channelname='brutMessage'; <====  code=2200 [Invalid query] message="PRIMARY KEY column "channelname" cannot be restricted 
                                                                                            (preceding column "ColumnDefinition{name=time, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.ReversedType
                                                                                            (org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.TimestampType), kind=CLUSTERING_COLUMN, componentIndex=0, 
                                                                                            indexName=null, indexType=null}" is either not restricted or by a non-EQ relation)"
```

---

#### Third table (messages_test2):

```sql
PRIMARY KEY (deviceid, channelname, time)) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (channelname ASC, time DESC)
```

```sql
SELECT * FROM messages_test2 WHERE deviceid = '1DB8D' AND time >= 1438853606718 ; <==== code=2200 [Invalid query] message="PRIMARY KEY column "time" cannot be restricted 
                                                                                        (preceding column "ColumnDefinition{name=channelname, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type,
                                                                                        kind=CLUSTERING_COLUMN, componentIndex=0, indexName=null, indexType=null}" 
                                                                                        is either not restricted or by a non-EQ relation)"
SELECT * FROM messages_test2 WHERE deviceid = '1DB8D' AND channelname = 'brutMessage' AND time >= 1438853606718 ; <==== OK
SELECT * FROM messages_test2 WHERE deviceid = '1DB8D' AND channelname = 'brutMessage'; <====== OK
```

### Do you have any suggestion to success my 3 requests ?

PS : Thanks to @BryceAtNetwork23 who explain to me how duplicate table with COPY TO/FROM method.

Comment: Please UP ! I need some help :(